# Do we have review queues on private beta?

Tags: support, editing

Do we have review queues on private beta?

How are people finding suggested edits and close votes, other than stumbling upon them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do have review queues, but as in any site, they are unlocked at various reputation levels (and for the duration of the private beta, those levels are a lot lower than they would be normally.)

Right now, the review queues are locked until you have 350 reputation, which you are close to getting! So it won't be much longer until you will see the "review" option at the top of the page.

Comment: Also, for reference, the full list of privileges is listed [here](http://pets.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: And in private beta due to less people to have access on review queue Community moderators helps. For our site Tim Post♦ has reviewed various posts. http://pets.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats

Comment: One point need to be mentioned that we didn't required 350 reputation to review edits made on oue own post.

Comment: @Skippy From what I remember from when Libraries was in private beta, there is usually one or two Community Managers who check the site most frequently, but if there is something that needs urgent attention, there is no reason we cannot consider bringing it up to the team as a whole, I don't think, it it is something that really needs taking care of right away (which I suspect would be quite rare, as the CM team is great at making sure we get what we need!).

Comment: @Skippy i am not able to answer that. Only community member can answer it better. I have seen three community member so far participating here Tim Post♦,Robert Cartaino♦ and Abby T. Miller♦.

Comment: @Skippy ping me in the pets general chat, we can talk there! :)

Comment: @Skippy If its the case, then its really great to have community moderator as an active user.

Answer (score -1):

The review queues exist; they're just not linked in the top menu like on other sites.  I was able to review close votes yesterday (<350 rep) via a link in the badges page describing the Custodian badge.  (I don't know why that one isn't available to everybody "up front", since we can all cast close votes.)